# Player progress calculation

Tags: algorithms, game-theory, arithmetic-progressions

I'm trying to calculate tennis players progress/advancement of several last games by using only scores of the games. For example - progress of the 5 last games:

1. 5-7, 4-6
2. 4-6, 6-4, 4-7
3. 6-4, 4-6, 6-2
4. 6-2, 6-0
5. 6-1, 6-2

Looking at the scores we can see that a player is in a good progress, but how to calculate it in percentage? Atleast progress percentage from one game to another, not all at once.

Can somebody help me with formula? I need ideas.
Thank you for your time :)

Comment: People love percentages.  What does it mean to say I am $10\%$ better than last week?  Presumably your matches are against the same opponent.  Maybe the opponent was hurt for the last two and this player was no better.  You might look up how the various sports rank their athletes.  There is also the [Elo rating system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elo_rating_system) which might be of interest.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Ross, I appreciate it. I will take a look on Elo rating system.